# JQuery submit with two keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

```
      <h:commandLink action="list?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true"
                    id="search">Search
      </h:commandLink>
      <h:link outcome="/admin/clients/list.xhtml" styleClass="btn btn-default ml15"    id="clear">
       Clear
      </h:link>
```

I have following tags. When i click link the page just reloads.
How can I execute the command on this link using jquery by pressing Alt+Enter?

Comment: Have you tried it at all?

Comment: Yes, It works with one key. But with two doesn't work

Comment: Can you edit your question and add what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var cmdLnk = $('#search');

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (e.altKey) {
        if (code === 13) {
            /* Since 'commandLink' renders as an 'anchor' tag (link) 
             * I assume that you will be able to trigger 'click' event. 
             * However, your question title says to 'submit' with two keys 
             * and, if this is the case, you can replace this last line and 
             * use '$(form).submit()' instead.
             */
            cmdLnk.click();
        }
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/c5Xgm/